# Promise still go to the next chain after I return res.end()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, bluebird

I'm using bluebird in node with express ,when I return res.end(),Promise still goes to the next chain,here's my code:

```
Promise.resolve(operate).then(function(data){
    if (!!data && data.length !=0) {
        log.info('success');
        return true;
    }else {
        log.warn('fail');
        return res.end();
    }
}).then(function(data){
    if(data) {
        log.info('done');
        return res.end();
    }else {
        log.warn('fail');
        return res.end();
    }
})
```

And I got 2 'fail' in the log if it's failed,how can i make it stop if i got 'fail' in the first time?Thank you!

bluebird version:~2.10.2;
node: 4.3.1;
express:~4.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return either an error or a rejected promise instead of `res.end`. This will skip all success handlers until the end of the promise chain (technically until the first rejection handler):

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => Promise.reject())
  .then(
     () => console.log('this does not run'), // <-- success handler
     () => console.log('this runs')          // <-- rejection handler
  );
```

So in your code:

```
Promise.resolve(operate).then(function(data){
  if (!!data && data.length !=0) {
    log.info('success');
    return true;
  } else {
    log.warn('fail');
    res.end();
    return Promise.reject(/* optionally pass an error */); // <--- return rejected promise
  }
}).then(function(data){
  // this won't run if previous promise rejects
})
```

Comment: thank you!  that can stop the chain goes down, but i got an "Unhandled rejection Error" in the log, how can i deal with that?

Comment: That's not really a problem, some browsers log promise errors that weren't handled but this only shows up in your log, doesn't affect the code in any way. If you don't want to see it, you can add an empty rejection handler or a `catch` clause that does nothing. Take a look at **Antonio Val's** answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

By definition the `then` method always return a Promise, so the chain is going to continue.

As it has been already pointed out you could reject the promise instead and catch it afterwards. If the error handling is the same in all cases you can use a `catch` at the end of the chain (putting a catch at the end is considered a good practice anyway).

```
Promise.resolve(operate).then(function(data){
    if (!!data && data.length !=0) {
        log.info('success');
        return true;
    } else {
        return Promise.reject('fail');
    }
})
.then(function(data) {
    // true is being returned above so it will enter here always
    // I guessed something instead of true could come here
    if(data) {
        log.info('done');
        return res.end();
    } else {
        return Promise.reject('fail'); 
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    log.warn(err);
    return res.end();
});
```

In this case returing a rejected Promise seems legit, but depending on the situation returning a rejected Promise to escape of the Promise chain could not be recommended because it can be mixed with a real rejection. In those case restructuring your chain could be the best option.